# weird usage of "außer"

Tags: meaning, preposition

> Sei immer du selbst. **Außer** du kannst ein Einhorn sein, dann sei immer ein Einhorn!

I haven't quite understood the meaning of **"außer"** here. I thought it is a preposition that comes with "Dativ". Now it is like a connecter that comes with "Hauptsatz". Please explain to me the meaning of it here in the previous sentence and please explain how "außer" works in this kind of usage (not a preposition).

Comment: The meaning as a conjunction is in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/au%C3%9Fer#Conjunction). It is kind of a weird, humorous sentiment, and it took me a while to "get" it, even after it was translated into English, but the grammar itself isn't really that difficult once you allow for the rather strange meaning. It makes a bit more sense if you combine the sentences since the *außer* really refers to the first sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right that *außer* can be a [preposition](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/au%C3%9Fer#Pr%C3%A4position) with dative (or, depending on context, with accusative or genitive). But it can also be a [conjuction](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/au%C3%9Fer#Konjunktion) that is synonymous with *es sei denn, (dass) …* In your example

> Sei immer du selbst. *Außer* du kannst ein Einhorn sein, dann sei immer ein Einhorn!

*außer* is a conjunction. The example can be rewrittes as follows:

> Sei immer du selbst. *Es sei denn,* du kannst ein Einhorn sein, dann sei immer ein Einhorn!
>
> <sup>(Always be yourself. Unless you can be a unicorn, then always be a unicorn!)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

"Außer" is used here as a conjuction meaning "unless", "except if".

German synonyms: "es sei denn", "ausgenommen".

See also:

- https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auszer_Konjunktion
- https://www.dwds.de/wb/au%C3%9Fer#2